# Creating a mirror or fork from a portion of a git repo?

Tags: git, google-chrome-devtools, blink

I'm working with a very large git repository (blink). I'm interested in forking and working with a portion of it (Source/devtools). I don't want to fork the entire repository, but I want to be able to pull/fetch changes that occur on the portion I am interested in.

Ideally, I'd like a repository that had the storage requirement for Source/devtools, but was aware that Source/devtools was part of a larger upstream (blink).

Is there a smart way to do this?

Comment: What does this have to do with Chrome's DevTools or Blink?

Answer (score 0):

Would [submodules](http://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Submodules) help? You'll need to break up your repo into [submodules](http://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Submodules) to get better control over portions of repos that you're interested in.